# How can I enhance the security level of my RSA code?

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, blinding

I am trying to enhance the security level of my RSA code that I implemented in Python. I tried to add blind operation, randomized algorithm to my RSA code (separately, not together), but I am not sure about the enhancement. Is it possible to enhance the security level of my RSA code by modifying it? If it is possible, ***what are the other ways to enhance the security level of RSA***, *or* ***is it correct to try to enhance the algorithm with blinding, or randomized algorithm?*** In short, how can I enhance the security level of my RSA code in Python? I really need help with this. Thank you!

Comment: "I am trying to enhance the security level of my RSA code" - against what attacks?

Comment: It may be common modulus attack or timing attack. Actually, it does not matter. I just want to enhance my RSA algorithm to prevent any attack. It does not matter which one.  @poncho

Comment: Firstly, use the [codereview.se] to improve the quality of your code where there are crypto-persons that provide answers, too.